# Monitoring Registry Changes

Tags: vb.net, registry, monitoring

I need to do some monitoring in the registry. For instance, toolbars like to add keys to *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID* and the like. They have unique IDs, and I can catch them by that. I've been doing some searching for such a thing. I've only come across articles not written in VB. [Things like this.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4502/RegistryMonitor-a-NET-wrapper-class-for-RegNotifyC)

It's really old, and converters I've found don't seem to be working. Is there anything current, in VB, that does for what I'm looking (something like FileSystemWatcher that I asked about just a day or so ago)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither [`Microsoft.Win32.Registry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx) or [`RegistryKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.aspx) types has any registry change watching support.

Therefore you can use:

- WMI events, or
- P/Invoke to Win32's [`RegNotifyChangeKeyValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724892.aspx)

Both of these will require some work.

However if you want to do this to see what other software is doing to the registry there are existing tools to do this. Perhaps the best known is Sysinternal's (now part of Microsoft) [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645). It will monitor file and registry operations (plus some other things) will powerful filtering and highlighting options.